# Why am i getting a SIGABRT error from using Visual Format?

Tags: ios, swift3, visual-format-language

I am using a book on how to make real life apps in swift3. I recently got an error from using Visual Format. It spaced my line out because I have show line numbers and the line of code I put didn't have a line number near it. Then when I pressed Run it gave me a SIGABRT Error. Why and how can I fix this. It didn't mention any errors in the book. If you want to know what book is it, its: Paul Hudson "Hacking with Swift". Please Help!

It gave me an error of ***Unterminated String literal***.

Here's my code:

```
view.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat:"V:|
            [label1(labelHeight@999)]-
            [label2(label1)]-
            [label3(label1)]-
            [label4(label1)]
            [label5(label1)]->=10-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: viewsDictionary
    )
)
```

Comment: Update the code in your question to be an exact copy and paste of the real code. And only post the code relevant to the error. Don't add text in the middle of the code to point out the issue. Add a comment on a separate line before the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know Swift well. Are you allowed to split a string literal across two lines of code like that? Split the line before or after the full string literal, not in the middle.

Comment: Im still a beginner, but i think you can do that. Thats the magic of swift that you don't have to use commas to extend lines. I actually figured it out on my own. It was that i didn't put the "metrics" word in metrics. Thanks for helping though i really appreciate the fast Responses.

Comment: You should post a proper answer showing exactly how you fixed the issue. It may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the `metrics` dictionary, yet you are trying to access `labelHeight` from it.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Encountered metric with name "labelHeight", but value was not specified in metrics or views dictionaries 
V:|[label1(labelHeight@999)]-[label2(label1)]-[label3(label1)]-[label4(label1)][label5(label1)]->=10-| 
                      ^'
```

**Edit**: as per rmaddy's suggestion, here's how one would fix it:

```
let metrics = [
    "labelHeight": <#labelHeight#>,
]
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat:"V:|[label1(labelHeight@999)]-[label2(label1)]-[label3(label1)]-[label4(label1)][label5(label1)]->=10-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: metrics,
    views: viewsDictionary
))
```

*Notes:*
1) the sample fix is broken over multiple lines merely for readability.
2) `<#labelHeight#>` will be translated to a placeholder when copied to Xcode.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it showed how to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Uupis and rmaddy, for helping me! I hope it can also help others.